# Boost::context on ARM Cortex-M?

Tags: c++, boost, embedded, cortex-m, bare-metal

According to documentation boost::context supports ARM systems with GNU/Linux OS. Just wondering - is it possible to use it on bare metal (without any OS) Cortex-M microcontrollers as well, or this is an additional port that should be written?

Comment: The simplest way of answering you question would be to compile it - your toolchain will soon tell you if there are missing dependncies, but it seems to me that the functionality provided is not OS dependent and can be implemented with standard setjmp/longjmp.  A word of warning though, when a colleague of mine attempted to incorporate boost libraries (not specifically `context`) into a Cortex-M bare metal project, he was astonished at the resulting code bloat, which he chose to blame on the ARM compiler rather than Boost itself; I am less convinced.

Comment: The problem is that in order to cross-compile boost with arbitrary toolchain one have to learn internals of boost build system, so, before delving into that task I decided to find if anyone already did this.

Comment: Looking at the [library requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/requirements.html) it seems that `context` includes assembler code, unless it explicitly supports the ARM Thumb-2 instruction set, you will not work out-of-the box build in any case.  That is I guess  what @xlrg's rather terse answer is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

boost.context does not support Cortex-M - only Cortex-A + ELF/MACH-O/PE

Comment: What specifically is the architecture constraint that causes it not to be supported?  Can you cite a reference for this assertion?  I cannot see what difference the object file format makes, and ELF is a common enough object file format in embedded systems.

Comment: I guess I answered my own question; the [library requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/requirements.html) state that the library contains assembler code.  That would seriously limit portability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, no boost lib would fit into most of Cortex-M, because there's a tiny to no C-runtime. Also there is no OS like Linux or so for most Cortex-M (as far as I know, e.g. Cortex-M0 or -M3), because they're mainly programmed as a bare-metal app or with a scheduler.

Additionally I'd not recommend using any C++ templates in a MCU, because they just blow up the footprint by MBs.

See [this](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/white-papers/Which-ARM-Cortex-Core-Is-Right-for-Your-Application.pdf) and a reply to [this question](https://community.arm.com/processors/f/discussions/6537/what-is-differene-between-cortex-a-cortex-m-and-cortex-r-series-of-arm)

Answer (score 0):

no, Cortex-M is low power processor and run on top of it real time operating system
in you case you need and arm cortex-A processor (arm application processor) which support of normal operating system